# Is the continuous ranked probability score invariant to strictly monotone transformations of the random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

Let $\omega$ be a random variable with CDF $F:\Omega\to[0,1]$ and support $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. The continuous ranked probability score (CRPS) is defined as

$$ S(F,\nu) = \int_{x\in\Omega} (F(x)-\mathbf{1}_{\nu \le x} )^2 dx $$

for all $\nu\in\Omega$.

Now let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a strictly increasing function and let $G:g(\Omega)\to[0,1]$ be the CDF of the random variable formed as $g(\omega)$.

I am wondering whether $ S(G,g(\nu)) $ = $S(F,\nu)$ for all $\nu\in\Omega$?

I am able to verify that this is true if I restrict attention to the case where $|\Omega|<\infty$, so that CRPS is a summation rather than an integral.

But when CRPS is an integral it looks like it may no longer hold.

Can anyone provide a proof or counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuous rank probability score is not invariant under strictly monotone increasing transformations as defined in the OP.

Suppose $(X,X')$ is an i.i.d vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, and let $F$ be the common cumulative distribution function of $X$ and $X'$.
Then
$$S(F,y):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\big(F(x)-\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,y]}(x)\big)^2\,dx=\mathbb{E}\big[|X-y|\big]-\frac12\mathbb{E}\big[|X-X'|\big]$$
The last identity follows from Fubini's theorem and the trivial identity
$$|X-Y|=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Big(\mathbb{1}_{[X,Y)}(x)+\mathbb{1}_{[Y,X)}(x)\Big)\,dx$$

If $g$ is a strictly monotone increasing function on $\mathbb{R}$, then $(g(X),g(X'))$ is an i.i.d vector and
$$S(g(X),g(y))=\mathbb{E}\big[|g(X)-g(y)|\big]-\frac12\mathbb{E}\big[|g(X)-g(X')|\big]$$

Consider $g(y)=2y$. If $X\in L_1(\mathbb{P})$ and $X$ is not a constant,
$$S(2X,2y)=2S(X,y)\not\equiv S(X,y)$$

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. Should the expression be 
$$S(F,y):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\big(F(x)-\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,y]}(x)\big)^2\,dx=\mathbb{E}\big[|X-y|\big]-\frac12\mathbb{E}\big[|X-X'|\big]$$ following equation (21) of [Gneiting and Raftery 2007](https://sites.stat.washington.edu/raftery/Research/PDF/Gneiting2007jasa.pdf)?

Comment: @jmshapir: I've just fixed the sign. Thank you!